# iOS - NSFileManager file not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am hosting my in-app purchase content with Apple. I have managed to download the contents and right now I want to save it in device.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dstPath error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:nil];
```

This code above is how I move the content downloaded to my desired location.

It seems to work fine and when I try to display the content it works. But when I stop and run the app again the files does not exist.

What am I missing?

My code:

```
- (void)processDownload:(SKDownload *)download
{
    NSString *path = [download.contentURL path];

    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *stickersDownloadedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *file in files)
    {
        NSString *fullPathSrc = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

        NSString *fileName = [fullPathSrc lastPathComponent];
        NSString *fullPathDst = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", fileName]];

        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fullPathDst error:nil];
        [fileManager moveItemAtPath:fullPathSrc toPath:fullPathDst error:nil];

        NSLog(@"fullPathDst: %@", fullPathDst);
        NSLog(@"file: %@", file);
        NSLog(@"key: %@", download.transaction.payment.productIdentifier);

        [stickersDownloadedArray addObject:fullPathDst];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stickersDownloadedArray
                                              forKey:download.transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

An example of `fullPathDst` is

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E921ADD6-B022-4DA2-8416-627DB44E679A/Documents/real4_12@2x.png
```

Comment: Where are you saving the data to? Could you print the `dstPath` and show it to us?

Comment: @Sulthan I have updated my answer

Comment: @Sulthan the file exists as long as I don't stop and run the app again.

Comment: Usually the sandbox path changes on application updates (e.g. new version downloaded from app store). However, every deploy from Xcode is also an update that changes the sandbox. You can't save absolute URLs.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you. its working now.

Comment: How do you know it seems to work fine when you're ignoring all errors???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An app's sandbox changes at different times. You must never store full paths to files. Only store a relative path.

In your case, only store the path relative to the Documents folder. When you reload the relative path when the app starts up, you recalculate the full path again.

Comment: I initially thought this gave me the clue to fixing this issue for me (changed from the `path` method to `relativePath`, but the issue is intermittent and it did come back fairly quickly.  FWIW, the only thing that seems to help consistently for my dev. env. is to restart the iPhone I am testing on.  It always works for a number of iterations after restarting completely.  Deleting app, signing out of sandbox, etc. do not help everytime.